# Menu not toggling

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get a menu to toggle when I click on a icon, but it is not working. I suspect it has something to do with selectors. Here is the code…
HTML

```
<div class="bild">
        <img src="face_kopia.png" class="ikon"/>
    </div>
    <div class="meny">
        <a href="">Home</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a href="">Gallery</a>
    </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Hide the tooglebox when page load
        $(".meny").hide();
        //slide up and down when hover over 
        $(".ikon").hover(function(){
        // slide toggle effect set to slow you can set it to fast too.
        $(this).next(".meny").slideToggle("slow");
        return true;
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change

```
$(this).next(".meny").slideToggle("slow");
```

to

```
$(".meny").slideToggle("slow");
```

it works

Answer (score 0):

Your statement was not correct

http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/204/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Hide the tooglebox when page load
    $(".meny").hide();
    //slide up and down when hover over 
    $(".ikon").hover(function () {
        // slide toggle effect set to slow you can set it to fast too.
        $(".meny").slideToggle("slow");
        return true;
    },function(){
        $(".meny").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide the tooglebox when page load
    $(".meny").hide();
    //slide up and down when hover over 
    $(".ikon").hover(function(){
    // slide toggle effect set to slow you can set 
    $('.meny').slideToggle("slow");
 });
});
```

Here is the working example
http://jsfiddle.net/5x7xv/9/